# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined JavaScript Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have the following function in my JavaScript code and when I run it shows me the following error `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` I am developing an SharePoing web application.

```
function startTest(quizID) {

   currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
   var quizName;
   context.load(currentQuizItem);
   var userName = user.get_title();

   var audiencenames = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audienca"];
   var straudience = audiencenames.toString();
   straudience = straudience.toUpperCase();
   straudience = straudience.replace(/\s/g, '');

   userName = userName.toUpperCase();
   userName = userName.replace(/\s/g, '');
   var rezultati = straudience.match(userName);
   alert(rezultati);
}
```

please help me!

Comment: context.executeQueryAsync() is missing

Comment: where should i Place this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.executeQueryAsync()` is missing in your code. Add it and try.

```
function startTest(quizID) {

    currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
    var quizName;
    context.load(currentQuizItem);
    var userName = user.get_title();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var audiencenames = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audienca"];
            var straudience = audiencenames.toString();
            straudience = straudience.toUpperCase();
            straudience = straudience.replace(/\s/g, '');

            userName = userName.toUpperCase();
            userName = userName.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var rezultati = straudience.match(userName);
            alert(rezultati);
        },

        function() {
            // handle error
        });
}
```

Also make sure that your variables are not `undefined` before using them. **Ex.** You can set condition before using them.

Comment: Thanks Atish for always helping me it is working perfect now. But I want to know why this function executeQueryAsync() should be here?

Comment: after loading anything like `context.load(currentQuizItem);`, you need this function to call that everything has been loaded successfully. To learn more about it please google. I can not add more here.